# Make imageview responsive

Tags: java, android, responsive-design

Make width and height  responsible to device width and height
We have posted image in our app  and it width and height is 250,320. 
We need to make it fit to screen without stretching. Is there any equation for finding the image new width and high according to device width

Comment: why don't you use glide or picasso i think they handle all these things ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen width and height from following methods

```
        public static  int getScreenWidth(Context c) {
          WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
          Display display = null;
          if (wm != null) {
            display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
          }
          Point size = new Point();
          if (display != null) {
            display.getSize(size);
          }
          return size.x;
       }
       public static  int getScreenHeight(Context c) {
         WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
         Display display = null;
         if (wm != null) {
         display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
         }
         Point size = new Point();
         if (display != null) {
         display.getSize(size);
         }
         return size.y;
      }
```

And then use any third party images rendering library like (picasso, glide) to resize the image according the width and height of the screen.